# Where should I post about a Raspberry Pi server?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, serverfault

I have a question about how much space I need for a server on Raspberry Pi.

> For example, I just bought a Raspberry Pi for running a server. I now need a SD card, but I don't know how much space to commit to at first. I might need it for the OS, and software for running the server. How much storage should I buy right now."

Should I post it on the Server Fault Stack Exchange, the Hardware Recommendations beta or the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange?

Comment: I'm pretty sure sever fault will not take that question but I have doubts if raspberry.se will take it. Shouldn't you add what you need that space on that SD card for?

Comment: What about Hardware Recommendations?

Comment: I don't think HwRec will take it, their quality guidelines are insane.

Comment: https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware Accepted answer lists flash drives as something you can ask about. Probably needs refining, but it would be on-topic

Comment: read the help: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic specially: Quality Guidelines

Comment: Smells a lot like a SuperUser question to me. It's definitely not ServerFault because it's not professional IT, but speccing out a pi for your own use seems to be appropriate to SuperUser.

Comment: It's unanswerable anywhere. The only person who knows how much space you'll need, is _you_. You'll need to do your research to come up with that personalised answer, but we can't do it for you. Stack Exchange is not a catch-all for "I haven't done my research yet" questions. Quite the opposite! Good luck.